# Is there a way to clear XDomainRequest.responseText in IE8

Tags: server-push, http-streaming, xdomainrequest

I'm implementing server push solution.

Is there a way to clear **XDomainRequest.responseText** of IE8, since it gets filled with the every response chunk?

(to get same effect as in Firefox xhr.responseText with multipart where it contains only the last response part.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is no way to change this behavior. 
Check out the comments where [former product manager for IE says it's a limitation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/06/comet-streaming-in-internet-explorer-with-xmlhttprequest-and-xdomainrequest.aspx?PageIndex=2&CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).